# Charging battery using a three phase alternator

Tags: battery-charging, charger, alternator

I want to charge a 672 VDC (182 kWh) battery pack using a 25 kW three phase alternator (679.8 VDC at 4000 rpm, current = 38.5 A). Can anyone suggest how to design the system? The alternator is powered by petrol engine. I am using three phase bridge rectifier (SEMIX501D17FS).

Comment: Powered by what? With what specs for regulation and protection?

Comment: Rectify the 3-phase AC to DC, feed to a charge controller. Both the rectifier and controller are advanced designs using high-voltage semiconductors like IGBTs. Not to mention cooling, battery monitoring and other important details. If you’re asking here, this might be where you should seriously consider hiring a consultant.

Comment: 1,200 volt SiC MOSFETs could be something to look at as an alternative to IGBTs.

Comment: Determine the battery type and the required charging voltage and current. Work back from that.

Comment: What chemistry battery pack? That will let us know how hazardous an operation you are thinking about.

Comment: Battery type is LFP Prismatic cells, 135Ah capacity.

Comment: Are you controlling the rotor current on the alternator?  If so, the specs for the rotor current would be very handy